# Okular lacks menus except in fully maximised mode

Tags: 11.04, unity, okular

Running Okular under Ubuntu 11.04 (w/ Unity): Okular doesn't have menus anymore (file, settings etc.) unless I maximise its window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Okular doesn't have menus anymore (file, settings etc.) unless I maximise its window."*

Yes it does. The menu is in the bar at the top of your screen just hidden until you put the mouse on it. (Silly I know, but that's the way the cookie crumbles).

Comment: Yes, you're correct that it works that way when it's *maximised*, but when it's not maximised I have no menus.

Comment: @BeSlayed: Are you trying what I suggested? When the window is not maximized the menu is still at the top of the screen.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's very odd behaviour. Most of the applications don't seem to work like that.

Comment: @BeSlayed: unity works like that. btw you can mark the question solved by clicking the arrow on my answer.